# What is Apache anyway?

Tags: apache

After some googling it seems Apache is a web server but I've stumbled upon apache documentation that looks almost identical to javadocs. Now I'm very confused. Everything I read says it's a web server but it has documentation like a programming language.

Is it a language or a web server?

Edit:
I misunderstood what Apache was. The documentation I was referring to is

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/BigFraction.html

Comment: Who upvotes this crap?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/BigFraction.html

Comment: As said in the URL, this doc is the doc for the Apache [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

Comment: @DannyBeckett I don't really see why it's an invalid question.

Comment: @X.L.Ant I'm sorry, I'm still in the process of learning. Can you explain?

Comment: Your question shows zero research effort. Simply going to Apache's website would answer this. FYI, Apache is the name of the organisation. Colloquially, the term "Apache" is used to describe Apache's famous webserver, called httpd.

Comment: Sorry if I caused any confusion but now I'm banned from asking questions on stackoverflow. I had good intentions in my questions and I phrased it well. If I could have upvotes to equalize my downvotes I'd be great. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache Software Foundation develops several Apache software projects. The Apache HTTP Server is one of these projects, as well as several Java libraries with JavaDocs.

I guess you got the documentation for the wrong Apache project. You may have a look at the [documentation of the Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/).

Answer (score 2):

[Apache](http://www.apache.org/) is not a webserver, it's a group of people that build great software.

You're looking at [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/), a collection of Java libraries. The library you're linking to in your comment is [Commons Math: The Apache Commons Mathematics Library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/). So yeah, Java documentation looks like Java documentation.

You'll want to look into [Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/).